# How to remove the shadow in image by using openCV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, shadow-removal

As title said, any solutions on how to remove the shadow in image via openCV? 
Thanks and appreciate any helps!

Comment: Below is a link to a website, which completely deals with shadows, its detection, removal etc.
Try it. It is more than sufficient, i think. It contains a lot of papers related to it. Try to implement it. http://cs.haifa.ac.il/hagit/courses/seminars/shadowRemoval/shadowRemovalPapers.html If it is not sufficient, googling "shadow removal in images" gives you lots of information and papers.

Comment: Here you have an [implementation](http://www.tuicool.com/articles/Y3amyq) that explains an algorithm for **shadow removal**. Here is another [method](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/111781/files/piecewise_shadows.pdf), simpler and maybe better to understand how to detect shadows in images. Good luck.

Answer (score 15):

For those who are looking for publication along with the source code of described algorithm, you might be interested by this paper: ["Single-Image Shadow Detection and Removal using Paired Regions"](https://web.engr.illinois.edu/~dhoiem/publications/cvpr11_shadow.pdf) by Ruiqi Guo, Qieyun Dai and Derek Hoiem.

They describe a method which works quite well and may be a very good start to implement your shadow-removing algorithm using OpenCV.

[image: Image processing algorithm description]

I found the source code [here](http://aqua.cs.uiuc.edu/site/projects/shadow.html), but for posterity and to prevent possibly dead links in the future (I have met many), I also uploaded it [on the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/shadow_code_10.1109CVPR.2011.5995725).