# How remove shades from partially shaded image

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, image-recognition

[image: example of partially shaded image]

I have image that is partially shaded.

How can I remove shades from my image?

Comment: I added example of image, I want to get image or without shade, or all shaded. Don't matter if result image will be black and white.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the shadow in image by using openCV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081930/how-to-remove-the-shadow-in-image-by-using-opencv)

Answer (score 1):

Following SOF might help you :

[How to remove the shadow in image by using openCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081930/how-to-remove-the-shadow-in-image-by-using-opencv)

There is a paper called "Simple Shadow Removal" in above link. Try to implement it.

Comment: This is good, but are there any library or implementation of this algorithms.

Comment: there are very few shortcuts i am afraid. mostly ppl need to code the stuff standard libraries do not provide.

Comment: me too have that problem several times. Algorithm may be simple, but the people writing it wrap the algorithm in a set of complex mathematical equations and keywords, so that common people won't understand it.

Comment: This should probably have been marked as *possible duplicate*, since the answer doesn't bring any extra relevant information.

Comment: Yeah, i knew it. In meantime , i was trying to implement any simple shadow removal algorithm and post it here, since this subject is always asked ( And i couldn't do it yet, due to above mentioned difficult keywords and equations in the paper)