# Which function in opencv can detect and remove shadow of object?

Tags: java, c++, opencv

Helo everyone,

i wonder if opencv have any function which detect and remove shadow of ball. I would like to detect circle in outside (a place which have some sunshine or light ). But my problem here is i don't know some function that can help me to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is an [implementation of Shadow removing with OpenCV](http://www.tuicool.com/articles/Y3amyq) an this  [C++ source code and grouth truth for shadow detection / removal](http://arma.sourceforge.net/shadows/)  . see this thread [How to remove the shadow in image by using openCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081930/how-to-remove-the-shadow-in-image-by-using-opencv)

Comment: No. :( But i found this [andriod-java-opencv](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=android-opencv-template-master/opencv/src/main/java/org/opencv/video/BackgroundSubtractorMOG.java) - maybe you can find somethig useful here. [how to detect and remove shadow of a object - another example](http://answers.opencv.org/question/63470/how-to-detect-and-remove-shadow-of-a-object/?answer=65275#post-id-65275)

Comment: Ok maybe i will research more obout it. Thank you so much for your help :))