# How to remove the shadows from these pictures using python opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

How to remove the shadows of the seeds? Also I would like to know if there is a way to change the color of all the seeds to red colour?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why not make it easy on yourself and use proper illumination when taking the picture? — Also, please refrain from asking multiple questions at once, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

It seems rather easy to detect the seeds since your background is homogeneous. You can start by some simple image processing (contrast enhancement, thresholding, contour detection) to detect the seeds and then you can plot red blobs (with the same area as the detected regions) on the original image.   As for the shadows, you can check this question ([How to remove the shadow in image by using openCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081930/how-to-remove-the-shadow-in-image-by-using-opencv)).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve with [this paper](http://dhoiem.web.engr.illinois.edu/publications/cvpr11_shadow.pdf) and it will make you interesting.

The algorithm described there works quite well and this will be a good example for you in using opencv.

And you can find the source code [here](http://aqua.cs.uiuc.edu/site/projects/shadow.html)

Regards.